# Defining dynamic variables in loop and combining content

Tags: r, loops, dynamic, variable-names

I'm new to R and cannot figure out the following problem in dynamically assigning multiple values to variables in a double loop:

I want to generate variables that differ in 
a) their names that are already stored in var_names
b) put data from an excel file into them by looping over the sheet names

Assume an excel file with 3 sheets; I compiled one for this example; you can find it [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/axl6u57ba4ukxcv/file.xls?dl=0).

```
var_names <- c("a", "b", "c")
cell_ranges <- c("A1:A2", "B1:B2", "C1:C2")
sheet_names <- c("sheet_1", "sheet_2", "sheet_3")
```

For a single variable x, the code would look like that:

```
x <- c()
for (sheet in sheet_names) {
    x<-c(x, read_excel("file.xls", sheet = sheet, range="cell range that
                        fits x; e.g., A1:A2"))
}
```

But I don't want to do that for each single variable; I want a loop over these to be computed variables, something similar to that:

```
for (i in 1:length(cell_ranges)) {
  for(sheet in sheet_names){
    assign(paste(var_names[i], "", sep=""),
           read_excel("file.xls", sheet = sheet,
                      range=cell_ranges[i]))
  }
}
```

Needless to say, it doesn't work because only the value from the last excel sheet is stored in the respective variable.

I tried to change the assign code like that but it didn't work

```
assign(paste(var_names[i], "", sep=""),
       c(var_names[i],
         read_excel("file.xls", sheet = sheet, range=cell_ranges[i])))
```

How can I change my loop so that my final variables contain the respective values of all sheets?
With the sample sheet the result should look like a list of 3 for each of a, b, and c.
I'm aware that being new means that I might have not expressed my needs clearly enough; please let me know and I'll try to explain in more detail. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, could you please try to make a more  [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? You'll have a much better chances of getting a great answer!

Comment: Forget `assign`. It's a function for experts and not to be misused by beginners. Just put all these variables in a list, e.g., `L <- list(); L[[var_names[i]]] <- ...`.

Comment: Thanks, Roland. I understand that you warn me about using assign. Yet, I cannot figure out how a list would solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The trick was to store the data first in an additional variable "a" and then use "a" to assign the data to the final variable

```
for (i in 1:length(cell_ranges)) {
  a <- c()
  for(sheet in sheet_names) {
    a <- c(a, read_excel("file.xlsx", sheet = sheet,range=cell_ranges[i]))
    assign(var_names[i], a)
  }
}
```